# Replacing old switch to new switch 2 way 2 gang. Different code name

Tags: switch

I am replacing the old switch to new switch (2 way 2 gang). The top one is the new switch. The bottom one is the old switch. L11 and L12 are no cable connected.

I can't figure out where to put these wires properly on the new switch. Any all help will be greatly appreciated!! Thank you.

[image]

Updated Drawing as below
I just found that I label the wrong name for L2 and L21
[image]

Comment: Make sure your switch has TUV, the BSI Kitemark, or other appropriate testing lab approval as required by your jurisdiction. We often see the alternate naming system on "mail-order switches from overseas" including via Amazon warehouses...  which do not comply with local quality standards and are unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

### This is simple

Your existing setup uses the two-way switches as simple single-pole on/off switches, but even if that wasn't the case, this is simply a case of translating the labels on the old switch to the labels on the new switch:

- L1 and L2 are the incoming power connections on the existing switch, and translate to COM1 and COM2 on the new switch, respectively
- The currently unconnected L11 terminal corresponds to LA2 on the new switch, which will be left unconnected
- As a result of this, the wire from L12 on the old switch gets connected to LA1 on the new switch
- On the other side, the wire from L21 on the old switch gets connected to LB2 on the new switch
- From there, we can deduce by process of elimination that LB1 is left unconnected, corresponding to the unconnected L22 terminal on the old switch

Comment: Please help me check for the updated drawing. The label L2 and L21 label wrongly.

Comment: @e12345678 -- the labeling switch doesn't change anything really since these switches are being used as single pole switches